# Perl list in boolean (scalar) context in while loop

Tags: perl, boolean-expression, scalar

I'm staring at this code in perl LWP::Protocol.pm and I don't understand how the loop would ever exit:

```
 while ($content = &$collector, length $$content) {
     $content_size += length($$content);
     # more here
 }
```

In my interpretation, I am thinking this is a list of 2 elements in scalar context, so the result that the while loop is testing is the length of the list, which is always 2 and never false.  How does this really work?

Comment: This is an odd piece of code, don't worry if you feel confused. Using the comma operator like this is unusual. I suppose someone struggled to come up with a loop condition that also refreshed the variable. It might be somewhat more obvious to write `while (length ${ $content = &$collector })`. For some weird reason this code returns a reference to a scalar -- some sort of premature optimization attempt perhaps -- and that is making things difficult. If they had not done that, you could just say `while (length $content = &$collector)`, or even just `while ($content = &$collector)`

Comment: https://metacpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/source/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm#L157 definitely a bad idea to use it in production code.

Comment: @mpapec I just realized that using `&` will make the collector inherit the current `@_`, which seems to be `my ($self, $arg, $response, $collector) = @_;` I assume that the collector sub does not use `@_`, or else this would be a hot pile of steaming cowflop. It could propagate the erroneous `@_` to another sub though, affecting the `$self` object throughout the module. Hard to analyse how serious this is, though.

Comment: Unless you explicitly want to use the current `@_`, the correct way to write that code dereference would be `$collector->()`. I feel like this could be an unintended bug.

Comment: `$collector->(@_)` also comes to mind if parameters need to be passed.

Comment: @TLP `&$collector()` would work too, though I do prefer `$collector->()`

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at the [operator precedence](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) in the documentation. There you'll see that `=` has a higher precedence than `,`. This means first it does `$content = &$collector` due to the higher precedence of `=` compared to `,`. Then it does `length $$content`.

Continuing with the documentation about the [Comma Operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) one will find:

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its left argument, throws that value away, **then evaluates its right argument and returns that value**.

Thus the result in this case will be the right one, i.e. `length $$content`. This will then be used as the condition inside `while`.

Comment: So like I said, the list is 2 elements, the "$content=&$collector" element, and the "length $$content" element - where am I going wrong and why does the while ignore the first element of the list?

Comment: @snoopyjc There is no list. Scalar comma operator is different than the commas in a list. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator

Comment: @snoopyjc: I've updated the answer to include more details based on the comment from Shawn.

Comment: This answer mistaunderstands the OP's question. They wonder why `scalar( A, B )` is different than `@a = ( A, B ); scalar( @a )`

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking this is a list of 2 elements in scalar context

Correct.

Technically, the documentation calls it [the comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) when it's used in scalar context,<sup>[1]</sup> but the operator is still called `list` internally.

The only real problem with that statement is the choice of word *element*. Operators have *operands* (which are *expressions*), not *elements*. *Element* is used to refer to the members of data structures, which isn't applicable here.

> so the result that the while loop is testing is the length of the list,

No.

You think some kind of list data structure gets produced, and it's then coerced into a scalar. This is a common misunderstanding, but it's not how context work at all. Scalar context doesn't coerce lists into their count; scalar context causes the operators to return a scalar from the start.<sup>[3]</sup> An operator in scalar context must produce exactly one scalar. And what that scalar is [up to each individual operator](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416).

A list/comma operator in scalar context doesn't return the length of anything. It evaluates each of its operands but the last in void context.<sup>[2]</sup> Then, it evaluates the last one in scalar context and returns the resulting scalar.

In other words,

```perl
scalar( EXPR, EXPR )
```

is similar to

```perl
scalar( do { EXPR; EXPR } )
```

---

1. It also goes out of its way to call it a binary operator, when 1) people don't think of it a binary operator, the generated operator isn't a binary operator, and 3) it makes absolutely no difference if it's a binary operator or not. Weird.
2. If the list is the last operand of a sub or the operand of a `return`, and if the sub is evaluated in scalar context, they will be evaluated in scalar context instead. This is a basically a WONTFIX bug.
3. In fact, there's no such thing as lists in that sense even in list context. When we say "passes a list" or "returns a list", we simply mean "adds a number of scalars to the stack". No "list" gets created.